# Why doesn't Pakistan have any strong cooperation with Turkey like China?

Tags: pakistan, turkey

China has strong military bond with Pakistan. Recently China pledged to invest USD 47 billion in Pakistan.

Turkey is a friend of Pakistan for a long period of time.

Why doesn't Pakistan have any long term strong partnership with Turkey in the trade or military sectors like China does? Why doesn't Pakistan get Turkey to invest in Pakistan? Why doesn't Pakistan buy lots of Turkish made military equipments? For instance, Pakistan could have bought T-129 helicopters instead of Mi-28 from Russia.

Comment: Are you sure that, within the limits of Turkey's budget and priorities, that Turkey and Pakistan don't have a high or meaningful level of [trade and military cooperation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pakistan%E2%80%93Turkey_relations)? China shares a land border with Pakistan and, being comparably wealthy, spends a fair amount of soft-power money on its neighbours. i.e. If China gives Pakistan more it's probably because China can afford ($) to have a larger sphere of influence and wants to shift toward soft power in any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both nations are founding members of ECO (Economic Cooperation Organization). They also both belong to D-8 (Developing 8 Countries). They've worked on a preferential trading agreement, bilateral trade had grown to nearly $1 billion in 2010, and a container train service connecting Islamabad and Istanbul opened in 2009. There are plans for a passenger train service.

Pakistan and Turkey have long standing military cooperation dating back to 1954, they both belonged to CENTO from 1955 to 1979 when the treaty was dissolved after Iran withdrew, and Turkey supports Pakistan in the Kashmir conflict. Both nations belong to the OIC (Organisation of Islamic Cooperation).

I would challenge the assertion that Pakistan and Turkey do not have meaningful trade or military cooperation, particularly given that there's about 2,000 miles between them.

Answer (score 5):

You must understand that Turkey is a member of NATO. There is only so much it can do. Additionally, Turkey's foreign policy has been a disaster under Erdogan. It has lost more friends than gained. Turkey tried to gain influence in Afghanistan, but that is no longer to be seen now. While there are certainly no fractures between Turkey and Pakistan, the relationship seems to be dormant when compared to before. The relationship was once robust but now it is different. Turkey's priorities differ from those of Pakistan's with respect to Afghanistan. The Turks support(ed) the Northern Alliance and Pakistan support the Taliban. Again Turkey has indulged the Uyghurs of China, probably at the behest of NATO and their own nationalist feelings, Pakistan doesn't want to get involved. This has probably created the greater differences.

Comment: Why do you say so?

Comment: +1 for the conflicting interests in Afghanistan and China between Pakistan and Turkey. Only thing that's missing is that Turkey has historically been more inclined to look westwards since Ataturk and been more reserved with ties to the East.

Answer (score 0):

Some good reasons there are:

- China is close, they have shared border
- China is blocking with Pakistan, to counter-weight India influence. There is long-term conflict between Pakistan and India. And some border tensions between India and China.
- Maybe Pakistan want to be a bit independent from its western allies and doing a "multi-vector" politics

Comment: T-129 helicopter ... https://www.dailysabah.com/defense/2018/03/23/turkey-pakistan-close-to-finalizing-atak-helicopter-deal

Comment: Turkish corvette sell ... https://aa.com.tr/en/turkey/turkey-signs-deal-to-produce-4-corvettes-with-pakistan/815631

Comment: Submarine upgrade ... https://aa.com.tr/en/corporate-news/turkish-firm-wins-pakistani-submarine-upgrade-contract/596714

Comment: Really, I don't say "there is no at all". I gived some reasons, why deals with China are so strong.

Comment: Or is it a link war?) Standalone links are not a proof. All can be sen in compare. And if we compare, we'll see that there is much more from China

Comment: See the original question.

Comment: Do not understand you. Question is about "why?". I gave some reasons why. You gave some links about Turkey-Pakistan military trading. Do I say "there is no military trading at all"?

Comment: This is my final comment.  That question was posted a while ago. Recent developments demonstrate Turkey has pushed gas on Turk-Pak relations. Although, nowhere near China, Turkey is a strong and tested ally of Pakistan.